# restoring bundle path to default after accidentally erasing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I'm running a Mac, using Terminal, working with Ruby on Rails.

I was trying to figure out where bundle install gemfiles on my machine. So I ran the command

```
bundle --path
```

and now it appears my machine does not know where any of my gem files are located. How do I restore it to it's original functionality?

Here is the error...

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/theDanOtto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/Users/theDanOtto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby: invalid option -D  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/theDanOtto/Dropbox/Sites/Current Development/ClashOfClanV2/path/ruby/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `bundle install --system`.